# How to pull data from a MySQL database into a stylesheet in it's own file/folder?

Tags: php, mysql, css, database

I am building a website template. This template I will use for 20 of my websites. I am making it database driven. This way when I want to edit it I can do so from my database with out ever uploading anything or with out having to edit the item/property on each page.

I want to be able to put the css properties for color in my database. Here is a bit of my code. This code is the css.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: <?php echo $styles_query_result[1]['a_color']; ?>;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: <?php echo $styles_query_result[1]['a_link']; ?>;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: <?php echo $styles_query_result[1]['a_visited']; ?>;
}
```

Now, so long as the styles are on the main page this code above works. Once I create a style sheet and attach it so that the styles are in their own folder as styles.css the code no longer functions. I do not wish to keep the styles on the main page.

How can I pull the data in my database into the stylesheet once the styles are in their own file and folder. styles.css is in a folder in the root.

Folders/files in the root:

index.php (removed the styles from this page)

css (and put the styles in here. styles.css inside this folder)

images

includes

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to put php code in a `.css` file. This code will not be executed, as stylesheets are downloaded fo the client _as-is_.

Comment: Derp. Should have known that. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: In order to do this, you will have to echo your style declarations directly into the php file where you can inject the colors from the database. OR create a php file that monitors changes in your database and recreates a cached copy of the stylesheet.

Comment: Yes. Rename it to i.e. `styles.css.php` and do some `header()` work in the beginning.

Comment: why don't you load the attributes as javascript variables and apply the css using javascript/jquery?

Comment: No sorry you can not do it in css file. Instead you can use jquery as `$('a).css({'color':'<?php echo ["a_color"]'});`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a database template you can use it to create a .css file without using php inside the .css file.

If you have two tables:

[image]

You can use that to create a css file. Pseudo code:

```
<?php

    //$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhist;dbname=cms', 'root', 'root');

    //$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `selector`");
    //$query = $query->fetchAll();

    $query = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'selector' => '.thisone'),
        array('id' => 2, 'selector' => '#thatone'),
        array('id' => 3, 'selector' => '.body')
    );

    $probs = array(
        1 => array(
            array('id' => 1, 'selector_id' => 1, 'css_element' => 'border', 'element_value' => '1px solid'),
            array('id' => 2, 'selector_id' => 1, 'css_element' => 'padding', 'element_value' => '10px')
        ),
        2 => array(
            array('id' => 1, 'selector_id' => 2, 'css_element' => 'border', 'element_value' => '1px solid')
        ),
        3 => array(
            array('id' => 1, 'selector_id' => 2, 'css_element' => 'width', 'element_value' => '40px'),
            array('id' => 2, 'selector_id' => 2, 'css_element' => 'height', 'element_value' => '40px')
        )
    );

    $css = '';
    foreach($query as $selector){
        //$properties = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE `selector_id` = $selector->id");
        //$properties = $properties->fetchAll();

        $properties = $probs[$selector['id']];

        $rules = '';
        foreach($properties as $element){
            $rules .= "\n \t$element[css_element]:$element[element_value];";
        }

        $css .= "$selector[selector]".'{'."$rules \n".'}'."\n\n";
    }

    $fp = fopen('style.css',"w");
    fwrite($fp,$css);
    fclose($fp);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo "$css";
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Result will be:

```
.thisone{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px; 
}

#thatone{
    border:1px solid; 
}

.body{
    width:40px;
    height:40px; 
}
```

You can add a table with css_file(id, name) and then add a css_file_id to selector table. Then you can also write multiple files.

Also you can create an editor form where you can add/remove/change css rules/selectors/files.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I am applying it now to see.

Comment: I LOVE IT exact what i was looking for, i hope i can implement this into my : [header builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzXxGV9KZVk)

Comment: i seem not so lucky to get the `$probs` array builded from the database