# php multidimension array generated from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am working on a code where i got most of the functionality from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19582946/1316372

But i tried to fetch the data from a Mysql database as following:

```
//my 2 db queries
  $query = array();
  $properties_array = array();

  $selector_query = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM bts_selectors");
  while ($selector = tep_db_fetch_array($selector_query)) {
  $query[] = array('id' => (int)$selector['id'], 
                         'selector' => $selector['selector']
                         );
 }

 $properties_query = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM bts_properties WHERE selector_id= '".(int)$selector['id']."'");
  while ($properties_result = tep_db_fetch_array($properties_query)) {
  $properties_array[] = array('id' => (int)$properties_result['id'], 
                            'selector_id' => (int)$properties_result['selector_id'],
                            'css_element' => $properties_result['css_el'],
                            'element_value' => $properties_result['css_val']
                         );
} 

//this is a working static array
$probs_good =array(
    1 => array(
        array('id' => 1, 'selector_id' => 1, 'css_element' => 'border', 'element_value' => '3px solid'),
        array('id' => 2, 'selector_id' => 1, 'css_element' => 'padding', 'element_value' => '10px')
    )
); 
///here the output should be generated
$css = '';
foreach($query as $selector){

    //$properties = $probs_good[$selector['id']]; //this the working static array
    $properties = $properties_array[$selector['id']];

    $rules = '';
    foreach($properties as $element){
        $rules .= "\n \t$element[css_element]:$element[element_value];";
    }

    $css .= "$selector[selector]".'{'."$rules \n".'}'."\n\n";
}
echo "<pre>";
echo "$css";
echo "</pre>";
```

I am aware that the way i go over the `foreach` requires that the array should have the same structure as the  `$probs_good`, but honestly i fail with each try.
In the post i refer to there is a quoted query made.
I made some attempts to comply to that also.
For now i thought it would be better to just show clean/simple code and explain what i tried to achieve.

Comment: As i expect the answer soon will be closed, I'll need to do some more investigation.

Comment: I hope it will not be closed before i can accept my own answer, so it will be help full for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after doing the research i found the solution (SO EASY, BUT WHEN NEVER HAD TO.....)

```
      $selectors_array = array();
      $selector_query = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM bts_selectors");
      while ($selector = tep_db_fetch_array($selector_query)) {
      $selectors_array[] = array('id' => $selector['id'], 
                             'selector' => $selector['selector']
                             );
    }

    $css = '';
    foreach ( $selectors_array as $selector ) { 
    $rules = '';

    $properties_query = tep_db_query("SELECT * FROM bts_properties WHERE selector_id = '" . $selector['id'] . "' ");

   while ($properties = tep_db_fetch_array($properties_query)) {    
    $rules .= "\n \t$properties[css_el]:$properties[css_val];";
    }
        $css .= "$selector[selector]".'{'."$rules \n".'}'."\n\n";
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    echo "$css";
    echo "</pre>";
```

Generated and wanted output:

```
.thisone{
border:1px solid;
padding:10px; 
}

#thatone{
border:1px solid; 
}

.body{
width:40px;
height:40px; 
}
```